# What's the difference between <MaskedTextInput /> and <MaskedInput /> in react-text-mask?

Tags: reactjs, input

In the common react library react-text-mask, what's the difference between these two controls and when should one use each?:

- `<MaskedTextInput />`
- `<MaskedInput />`

The documentation unfortunately does not provide much help here: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/master/componentDocumentation.md#readme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having browsed the doc a bit, it looks like that they are the same, it's only how they are named at import that changes: https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/react#readme

You can import it like that it will be the same: `import MyGreatMaskedInput from 'react-text-mask'`.

Comment: I see, because the component is the default export from this module, we can import it as any name we choose? And the docs happen to use a couple different names, which is confusing, but in reality just the same component?

Comment: Yes to both ! =)